# Apache 2.0.55/PHP 5.3.5 Hangs

Tags: php, apache-2.2, php5, xampp

Recently inherited a Windows 2k3 server running XAMPP, including ancient copies of PHP, MySQL and Apache.

I'm attempting to install a second, up-to-date PHP installation on the machine so I can reference that in future instead of XAMPP's old one. Apache starts up with this new PHP installation happily.

Unfortunately, when Apache references the new PHP install, whenever I try a view a page (even a **non-PHP page**)  it hangs. The server simply doesn't respond to any HTTP request - it doesn't crash either. It just sits there with the connection open. There are no errors/warnings/notices in either the PHP or Apache logs.

I've pretty much ruled out PHP's extensions (by process of systematic elimination) and most of the INI settings. I've tried reinstalling PHP from scratch.

The PHP installation is PHP 5.3.5 x86 thread-safe compiled w/ VC6.
The Apache installation is Apache 2.0.55.

Anyone encountered similar behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reverting to PHP 5.2 resolved the issue. No idea why, though.